# How do I custom the alert view when making a phone call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

currently I'm using `UIWebView` to make phone calls

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://123456789"];
[self.callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

when I touch on a button to make call, an `UIAlertView` appears and ask for confirmation with title `123456789`

How can I change its title and message ?

Thanks.

Comment: you want to change alertView title and message?

Comment: not exactly, it's an `UIAlertView` that automatically appears when I try to make a phone call programmatically. However, I cannot access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `UIWebView`, just present a `UIAlertView` to the user asking if he/she want to call. Also there are no `//` in the [`tel:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) scheme, so `tel:123456789` is correct.

Then just open open the [`tel:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) url via [`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14).

Also do not forget the check whether the users device can make phone calls:

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:telURL]) {
 // Present the user with the dialog to start the call
} else {
 // inform the user that he/she can't call numbers from their device.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I thought using `tel` or `telprompt` is not recommended by Apple, even it works. Back to the question, I did what you said and the `AlertView` which I mentioned in the question appears on top of my custom `AlertView`. Seem likes iOS 7 forced it this way.

Comment: Only `tel` is documented by Apple. `telprompt` is not documented or referenced by Apple, which means you should not use it as it can be removed at any time Apple. If you use `tel` to dial no dialog will be shown. Just DO NOT USE a `UIWebView`, just call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL]`